# Android custom listadapter always deleting the last item

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Good day,

I am trying to refresh my knowledge in android programming
by creating a simple memo app with custom adapter list.

My problem is, even I call "NotifyDataSetChanged();",
the value deleted in my list is always the last one.
Though when I refresh it, it will display the correct one.

Here is my code :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
List<Memo> memos;
Context context;
int [] imageId;


private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<Memo> _memos) {
    memos = _memos;
    context = mainActivity;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return memos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    Button deleteMemoBtn;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mViewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        mViewHolder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_memo, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mViewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mViewHolder.deleteMemoBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteMemoBtn);

        mViewHolder.tv.setText(memos.get(position).getMemoTitle());
        mViewHolder.tv2.setText(Integer.toString(memos.get(position).getMemoID()));

        mViewHolder.tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + memos.get(position).getMemoTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });  



        mViewHolder.deleteMemoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "deleted " + Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                memos.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });  


    }
    return convertView;
}


}
```

Hoping someone can lighten me up why this code is not working.
Thank you!

Comment: does the Toast show correct deleted position?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, I edited the "memos.get(position)" to "Integer.toString(position)" so I can check it properly, and yes, the toast now display the correct position. I have 4 item in my array and when I click the 3rd row in my list, it displays "deleted 2" (which is the 3rd item)

Comment: I check your code and I think that it correct. do you have demo project, if possible please share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Memo> memos;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;


    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<Memo> _memos) {
        memos = _memos;
        context = mainActivity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return memos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return memos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv2;
        Button deleteMemoBtn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mViewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            mViewHolder = new Holder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_memo, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mViewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mViewHolder.deleteMemoBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteMemoBtn);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.tv.setText(memos.get(position).getMemoTitle());
        mViewHolder.tv2.setText(Integer.toString(memos.get(position).getMemoID()));
        mViewHolder.tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + memos.get(position).getMemoTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        mViewHolder.deleteMemoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "deleted " + Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                memos.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: works like a charm! does the `else {
            mViewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }` is my problem?

Comment: Yes. You were holding only last viewholder.